# GAE JPA @OneToMany orphanRemoval + Cascade not working as expected

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, one-to-many

I have some really trouble with Appengine + JPA + Jersey , I woul not use this combination but i am forced by university (Project-Deadline 10.01.16 18:00 GMT+1)

I want to delete all "Lehrer" with refferences to a "Schule" when their "Schule" gets removed. When a "Lehrer" gets Removed "Schule" should still remain untouched. Here are my Classes:

---

```
@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Lehrer {
    @Id
    @XmlElement
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @XmlElement
    private String vorname;
    @XmlElement
    private String nachname;

    @Transient
    @XmlElement
    private String passwort;

    private String hash;

    private String salt;

    @XmlElement
    @Unowned
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Schule schule;

    ..getter&setters..

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Schule {
    @Id
    @XmlElement
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "schule", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Lehrer> Lehrerliste;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "schule", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Klasse> Klassenliste;

    ...getter&setter...
}
```

---

And the code for deleting a "Schule".

```
@DELETE
@Path("/id/{id}")
public Response deleteSchule(@PathParam("id") long id) {

    EntityManager em = EMF.get();
    Schule GesuchterSchule = em.find(Schule.class, KeyFactory.createKey("Schule", id));

    if (GesuchterSchule != null) {

        System.out.println("remove " + GesuchterSchule + "\n");

        em.remove(GesuchterSchule);

        em.close();
        return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
    }
    em.close();
    System.out.println("remove faild for id: " + id + "\n");
    return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
}
```

---

Now my Problem is that once deleting "Schule" the associated "Lehrer" Stay and now have a invalid "Schule" reference.

When setting the @ManyToOne of "Lehrer" to Cascade.All , the associated "Schule" get Removed once removing a "Lehrer"so it works that way , but not vice versa.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for any Help
- Flo

---

Update, Looks like when adding a "Lehrer" with Lehrer.schule as his "Schule" object , the Set in "Schule" is null.

---

Workaround by manually deleting cild items like goofiw suggested.

```
@DELETE
@Path("/id/{id}")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Response deleteSchule(@PathParam("id") long id) {

    EntityManager em = EMF.get();
    Schule GesuchterSchule = em.find(Schule.class, KeyFactory.createKey("Schule", id));

    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Lehrer e WHERE e.schule = :s");
    query.setParameter("s", GesuchterSchule);
    List<Lehrer> list = (List<Lehrer>) query.getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for (Lehrer lehrer : list) {
        em.remove(lehrer);
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    if (GesuchterSchule != null) {
        System.out.println("remove " + GesuchterSchule + "\n");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(GesuchterSchule);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
    }
    em.close();
    System.out.println("remove faild for id: " + id + "\n");
    return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
}
```

Comment: where does hibernate come into this? what datastore are you using?

Comment: sry i linked it wrong , using "datanucleus jpa v2"

Answer (score 1):

What might be happening is the reference to Schule is removed in the Lehrer table when the document is deleted, resulting in `null` for the Schule column.  When you look in the Lehrer table for the Schule row to delete, it no longer exists.  What you could do it remove any rows with a Schule of `null` in Lehrer when you delete a document of Schule.

Comment: thank you for your effort, i solved it that way , but i dont know if i should mark this as answer as it is more like a workaround :S